# database schema nested array

Tags: json, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a project which contains lots of nested data. Think of a comments sections of a website where people can comment on previous comments. The difference for me being a comment can be one of a number of different types. The json representation would be something like:

```
{
"children": [{
        "name": "comment",
        "children": [{
                "type": "comment",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "type": "note",
                "children": [{
                    "type": "comment",
                    "children": [{
                        "type": "note",
                        "children": []
                    }, {
                        "type": "comment",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "comment",
        "children": []
    }
]
}
```

Visually it would look something like: [image]

I'm struggling to figure out how to represent this in the database. Currently I'm thinking of using postgres but am happy to use the most suitable db for this. I know I could have a comments table and a notes table. Then each comment and note would have a parent_id and parent_type and order_number which relates it back to the parent. But it feels to me like there would be a better way. If anyone knows of one I'd love to hear it. Maybe it's the case that a relation db is not best suited for this?

Comment: What's the difference between a comment and a note?  Also, in your picture, what does the indention signify?

Comment: This is maybe where my comment/note example breaks down a bit but essentially they will hold different information. A comment might have some text and let’s same a number (for some reason), the note might just have some text. The indentation signifies the nested depth.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested depth"?  Are you commenting or noting on the comment or note just above in indentation.  In other words, are your comments snd notes like leaves in a tree structure.  Would it make sense to collapse and expand sections on your UI for clarity?

Comment: The visual there is really just a representation of the json which is essentially nested arrays of mixed data. Yes expanding/collapsing the UI does make sense but what I'm trying to figure out is the db schema.

Comment: We can't help you with the schema unless we understand the relationships.  I'd say combine the Comment and Note entity into one entity.  Just indicate which is which by the "number" containing a number or null.